# Deploying Ruby app to Elastic Beanstalk with custom extension, unable to load compiled file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been working on a Ruby extension for a project of mine, and I've gotten to the point where I'm ready to deploy it to elastic beanstalk. I decided to make a gem, not because it would really be useful to anyone else, but mostly just because I've never made one before. Anyways, I used mkmf in my extconfig.rb file to compile the extension:

```
# Loads mkmf which is used to make makefiles for Ruby extensions
require 'mkmf'

# Give it a name
extension_name = 'jeopardy'

create_makefile(extension_name)
```

Then, my gemspec:

```
Gem::Specification.new "jeopardy", "0.0.5" do |s|
  s.name        = 'jeopardy'
  s.version     = '0.0.5'
  s.date        = '2015-04-26'
  s.summary     = "Jeopardy Game Simulator"
  s.description = "A fast Monte Carlo simulation of the television game show Jeopardy!"
  s.authors     = ["Devin Shelly"]
  s.email       = 'devin@devinshelly.com'
  s.homepage    =
    'http://rubygems.org/gems/jeopardy'
  s.license       = 'MIT'
  s.extensions = %w[ext/jeopardy/extconf.rb]
  s.files = ["lib/jeopardy.rb", "lib/jeopardy/jeopardy.bundle"]
end
```

And finally, my rakefile:

```
require "rake/extensiontask"

Rake::ExtensionTask.new "jeopardy" do |ext|
  ext.lib_dir = "lib/jeopardy"
end

require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << 'test'
end

desc "Run tests"
task :default => :test
```

So anyways, I have everything set up there, I run rake compile, gem build, gem install, everything works great. I pushed it to rubygems here (https://rubygems.org/gems/jeopardy), then in my rails Gemfile, throw in gem 'jeopardy'. Everything's good, everything's working. However, when I try to deploy my app using elastic beanstalk, I get the following error:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- jeopardy/jeopardy.bundle
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.1.4/gems/jeopardy-0.0.5/lib/jeopardy.rb:238:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

That points to the last line in my lib/jeopardy.rb file, which is simply

```
require "jeopardy/jeopardy.bundle"
```

So, that's just the line which loads my extension after I've defined all the classes and methods that my C extension uses. If I ssh into my elastic beanstalk instance and check out the gem directory, the file does exist, it just won't load it for some reason. I'm running OSX on my dev machine and Linux on my EB instance, fwiw. Does anyone know why requiring the file fails there when it works on my machine?

Edit: Just did some playing around, if I remove that line from the installed version on my EB instance, it loads. If I create a .rb file and require it from the main jeopardy.rb file, it loads. If I require_relative the .bundle file, it still won't load. So, it's not an issue finding the file, it just doesn't like the .bundle file for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, figured it out. So, my code compiled to a .bundle file, but that's an OSX specific file. What I actually needed to do was include all my .h and .c files in the gemspec, then build the gem. Then, when installing the gem, those files would be built (which in the case of Linux, is a .so file). I also needed to add the following line to extconfig.rb

```
$CFLAGS += " -std=c99"
```

Otherwise, when attempting to install the gem on Linux, I was getting errors.